# In SceneKit, detecting the geometry around an enemy in order for it to navigate through an environment

Tags: geometry, scenekit

Building a project with Scenekit and trying to have enemies navigate around objects in the scene. I keep looking up collision detection or avoidance but all I get are articles about objects hitting each other, I have that working fine but what I need is a system in which one object is able to "see" another object and then do a set of actions. I understand the concept of rayCast style detection and have built stuff like this from scratch in 2D to detect walls etc. but wanted to use some of the existing methods in SceneKit for 3D geometry detection. I have tried something like this:

let aResult = enemyNode.hitTestWithSegment(from: theOrigin,to: theDestination,options: nil)

...But I keep getting nil or like random results.

If anybody has any advice, best practices or a good link to a Tut that would be great. I know gamePlayKit has an advanced set of enemy AI but I wanted to get a basic version going. Thanks!

Comment: The issue of `hitTestWithSegment()` not working is orthogonal to the AI problem, and it could be useful to have that function available, so I'd recommend first tackling that problem in isolation. For example, start by testing the function with a trivial scenario where you know a hit should be detected, e.g. a single cube at the origin and a segment passing through the origin. Then work your way out from there to see if you can figure out what the problem is. (Of course it's possible you may find it's a bug in the implementation.)

Comment: Thanks, I understand my question was layered. It’s just I know how to do the AI stuff just can’t seem to get the sensor side if things working. Your advice is sound, my initial tests were with a complicated system and I am trying again with a very simple scenario. So far with simple tests it’s still not working though, just need some guidance with the hitTest method(s). Thanks

Comment: It sounds like SceneKit is where the problem lies currently. Unfortunately, I'm not familiar with SceneKit, and can't help with that :( As for the AI, you said you already know how to do that part, but just in case it might be useful, I'll mention [steering behaviors](https://www.red3d.com/cwr/steer/gdc99/), in particular [avoid](https://gamedevelopment.tutsplus.com/tutorials/understanding-steering-behaviors-collision-avoidance--gamedev-7777), as it seems that might be applicable here (or maybe when you say you've already done this in 2-d, that's what you're referring to).